# Какие есть алгоритмы формирования Mesh-сети?

Tags: алгоритм, сеть, протоколы, mesh

Изучаю Mesh - сети, вроде все бы хорошо, но я так и не смог найти по какому алгоритму происходит "формирование" сети. Я понял что есть множество узлов - компьютеров и во время включения они просто связываются друг с другом? От такой связи мало смысла т.к. если кто-то кому-то захочет отправить пакет, то во первых кроме своего самого близкого соседа он не сможет никому его отправить т.к. никого больше "не знает"(все достаточно далеко), а во вторых непонятен маршрут перемещения пакета т.к. нет общей карты сети. Хотя, используется стандарт 802.11, но откуда и как берется какая-то информация об окружающих?

Поясните пожалуйста как происходит организация(самоорганизация) сети при включении(запуске) пользователей.

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов может быть множество. Как пример — протокол [AODV](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AODV), описанный в [RFC 3561](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3561). Список других возможных протоколов маршрутизации (вероятно, неполный) можно найти [в Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_mesh_network#Routing_protocols).